# Change variable in which polygon colors are based (in Carto)

Tags: carto

I have crossed a polygon layer with a dataset, and I can color the polygons depending on the value of one dataset variable. Is it possible with the builder to allow the user to switch the variable in which the polygon colors are based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **`STYLE BY VALUE`** a layer in CARTO BUILDER from the `STYLE` tab and then click that option after clicking on the color bar. [Here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value) you have a guide that explains step by step this feature.

In addition, final users can use [the new **autostyle** option](https://carto.com/blog/data-driven-maps-auto-style) on any histogram or category widget to style your layer depending on its data type and data distribution.

Comment: Hi Ramiro. That is what I have done to make the color depending on one variable. But I would like that ones the map is published, a user will be able to change the selected variable which marks the colors

Comment: I have added a new paragraph solving your issue after your last feedback.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted. It's an easy and nice way to change the variable. I still have some doubts about the polygon values, but that should be in another topic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey @javi mark it as answered if you think my answer solves your issue. In doing so the rest of the CARTO community will know how a final user could autostyle their layers.

Comment: Hi @ramiroaznar , I am new in here. How can I mark it as answered?

Comment: As explained [on the tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for beginners, you have to click on the tick ("✔") symbol.